# Gensim: raise KeyError("word '%s' not in vocabulary" % word)

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec, topic-modeling

I have this code and I have list of article as dataset. Each raw has an article.

I run this code:

```
import gensim    
docgen = TokenGenerator( raw_documents, custom_stop_words )    
# the model has 500 dimensions, the minimum document-term frequency is 20    
w2v_model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(docgen, size=500, min_count=20, sg=1)    
print( "Model has %d terms" % len(w2v_model.wv.vocab) )    
w2v_model.save("w2v-model.bin")    
# To re-load this model, run    
#w2v_model = gensim.models.Word2Vec.load("w2v-model.bin")    
    def calculate_coherence( w2v_model, term_rankings ):
        overall_coherence = 0.0
        for topic_index in range(len(term_rankings)):
            # check each pair of terms
            pair_scores = []
            for pair in combinations(term_rankings[topic_index], 2 ):
                pair_scores.append( w2v_model.similarity(pair[0], pair[1]) )
            # get the mean for all pairs in this topic
            topic_score = sum(pair_scores) / len(pair_scores)
            overall_coherence += topic_score
        # get the mean score across all topics
        return overall_coherence / len(term_rankings)

import numpy as np    
def get_descriptor( all_terms, H, topic_index, top ):    
    # reverse sort the values to sort the indices    
    top_indices = np.argsort( H[topic_index,:] )[::-1]    
    # now get the terms corresponding to the top-ranked indices    
    top_terms = []    
    for term_index in top_indices[0:top]:    
        top_terms.append( all_terms[term_index] )    
    return top_terms    
from itertools import combinations    
k_values = []    
coherences = []    
for (k,W,H) in topic_models:    
    # Get all of the topic descriptors - the term_rankings, based on top 10 terms
    term_rankings = []    
    for topic_index in range(k):
        term_rankings.append( get_descriptor( terms, H, topic_index, 10 ) )

    # Now calculate the coherence based on our Word2vec model
    k_values.append( k )
    coherences.append( calculate_coherence( w2v_model, term_rankings ) )
    print("K=%02d: Coherence=%.4f" % ( k, coherences[-1] ) )
```

I face with this error:

```
raise KeyError("word '%s' not in vocabulary" % word)
```

KeyError: u"word 'business' not in vocabulary"

The original code works great with their data set.

https://github.com/derekgreene/topic-model-tutorial

Could you help what this error is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could help answerers if you included more of the information around the error message, such as the multiple-lines of call-frames that will clearly indicate which line of your code triggered the error.

However, if you receive the error `KeyError: u"word 'business' not in vocabulary"`, you can trust that your `Word2Vec` instance, `w2v_model`, never learned the word `'business'`.

This might be because it didn't appear in the training data the model was presented, or perhaps appeared but fewer than `min_count` times.

As you don't show the type/contents of your `raw_documents` variable, or code for your `TokenGenerator` class, it's not clear why this would have gone wrong – but those are the places to look. Double-check that `raw_documents` has the right contents, and that individual items inside the `docgen` iterable-object look like the right sort of input for `Word2Vec`.

Each item in the `docgen` iterable object should be a list-of-string-tokens, not plain strings or anything else. And, the `docgen` iterable must be possible of being iterated-over multiple times. For example, if you execute the following two lines, you should see the same two lists-of-string tokens (looking something like `['hello', 'world']`:

```
print(iter(docgen).next())
print(iter(docgen).next())
```

If you see plain strings, `docgen` isn't providing the right kind of items for `Word2Vec`. If you only see one item printed, `docgen` is likely a simple single-pass iterator, rather than an iterable object.

You could also enable logging at the `INFO` level and watch the output during the `Word2Vec` step carefully, and pay extra attention to any numbers/steps that seem incongruous. (For example, do any steps indicate nothing is happening, or do the counts of words/text-examples seem off?)

Comment: this is orginal code https://github.com/derekgreene/topic-model-tutorial bit with my Dataset it face this error

Comment: Are you sure your `raw_documents` is filled properly, given your files-on-disk? Did you verify that the print statements I suggested show reasonable results of the proper format? Did you enable logging at the INFO level and look for anomalies? If you get the error you've gotten, there's no word `'business`' in the training corpus.